# Corner DIV with transparent filling

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a corner block, to create a one-page as in the photo below. But I ran into a problem.
I tried to make div slopes, but when looking at different resolutions it looked crooked.
[What i need screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eucfz.jpg)

(there was also a problem in that before these inclined divs there was a background image and some holes that left this div, the picture showed through.)[My Fail Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZMqa.png)

```css
.tri-index-right {
  background: #fff;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: skewY(4deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2; /*fail method*/
}
```

I can not understand how to extend this angle using the CSS method at width 100%.

```css
.1 {
  min-width: 500px;
}
#triangle-left {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 100px solid red;
 border-bottom: 100% solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="1">
<div id="triangle-left"></div>
</div>
```

I will be very grateful for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vw for full width or use svg

```css
.one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('https://imgur.com/a/kA3XA') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#triangle-left {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100vw solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div id="triangle-left"></div>
</div>
```

you can also use svg for this

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.svg-container svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #333; /* change color to white since */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <!-- main image -->
</div>
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" class="separator" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 100 L100 0 L100 100 Z"></path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Ty my friend for help <3

Answer (score 0):

you can also use multiple background image including a sharp gradient :

```css
header {
  min-height: 4em;
  background: 
  /* first the mask */
  linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 49.5%, white 50.5%) bottom left no-repeat,
  /* then the background image */
  url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300/abstract/1) 0 0;
  /* finally resize each image, in particular the mask */
  background-size: 100% 4em, cover;
  padding: 1em 2em 4em;
  color: white;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>whatever</h1>
</header>
<div>next content</div>
```

Comment: Thank u friend... <3